# How to show that $(\cot^{-1})^\prime(x)=-\frac{1}{1+x^2}$?

Tags: calculus, trigonometry

This is from a problem sheet that I'm having difficulty getting through.
The previous questions have asked me to;

- Compute $\cot^\prime(x)$ on $(0,\pi)$ which is $-\csc^2(x)$
- Check that $1+\cot^2(x)=\csc^2(x)$ which is true

And now I'm being asked to show that $\cot^{-1}:\mathbb{R} \mapsto\, (0,\pi)$ satisfies the above equation.

Apologies if this is a duplicate question, couldn't find an answer on here myself. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you know a formula (which you can deduce by implicit differentiation) for finding $(f^{-1})'(a)$ in terms of $f'(f^{-1}(a))$?

Comment: @scoopfaze we hadn't come across u-substitution in the module when this problem sheet was given out so it must be another method

Comment: @scoopfaze but $\cot (x) \neq \tan(\frac1x)$, but rather, $\cot x=\frac1{\tan x}$.

Comment: @TedShifrin we were given the formula that $(f^{-1})'(a)=\frac{1}{f'(a)}$ if that is what you mean?

Comment: Well, it's not correct as you typed it. Notice what I typed and your denominator ...

Comment: @AndrewChin you're right, got mixed up.

Comment: @TedShifrin so it should be $\frac{1}{f'(f^{-1}(a))}$ instead?

Comment: Yes, Karl. The way to convince yourself is to differentiate $f(f^{-1}(x)) = x$ by using the chain rule. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may use the [Inverse function theorem](http://Inverse%20function%20theorem) (i.e., the formula for the derivative of an inverse function), which implies that $\cot^{-1}(x)$ is differentiable and that
$$(\cot^{-1}(x))'=\frac{1}{-\csc^2(\cot^{-1}(x))}=-\frac{1}{\csc^2(\cot^{-1}(x))}$$
Then, you can use that identity:
$$\csc^2(\cot^{-1}(x))=1 + \cot^2(\cot^{-1}(x))=1+x^2 $$